# How to un-select a selected option in md-select multiple (in angularjs)?

Tags: html, angularjs

This is my code in html

```
 <md-select ng-model="vm.hostSettings.cohostLists"  value="{{vm.hostSettings.cohostLists}}" multiple="true">
  <md-optgroup >
      <md-option ng-value="host" ng-repeat="host in vm.coHostList" ng-selected="{{ vm.selectedUser.indexOf(host.user.firstName) > -1}}">{{host.user.firstName}}</md-option>
  </md-optgroup>
</md-select>
```

How to un-select a selected option in md-select multiple (in angularjs) ?

Answer (score -1):

I've got the answer.Change the html code as below

```
                        <md-select ng-model="vm.hostSettings.cohostLists"
                                   ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}" multiple="true">
                            <md-option ng-value="host" ng-repeat="host in vm.coHostList">{{
                                host.user.firstName}}
                            </md-option>
                        </md-select>
```

Comment: How is this `unselecting`??

Comment: Add ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}"  as md-select's attribute

Comment: as far as I know `trackBy` attr does not `unselect`

Comment: With my first code when de-select a selected option , it was not removing from the cohostLists.That was my problem.But by using the 2nd code when de-selecting the selected option it was removed from the cohostLists.so I could de-select the selected option